# Floated item breaks in IE7, works in IE8+

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've got a development site (http://www.tentenstudios.com/clients/swls/our-surgeon) that works well in FF, Chrome, and IE8+ but the right-corner image breaks in IE7 and I can't seem to figure out what's causing the problem.  The right-corner image is in a left-floated container DIV but there is also an absolutely-positioned graphic on top of it, not sure if that's got something to do with it or not.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Per request, here is a JSFiddle with (I think) the relevant code: http://jsfiddle.net/HyVcG/

Also, to see this work you can open the link with IE and hit F12 to bring up the development console, then click Browser Mode: IE9 and change it to IE7.

Comment: Creating a http://jsfiddle.net/ would probably be helpful so others can tinker with the code to help you out. You might also want to show a screen shot, as not many people will have IE7 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The widths and interior margin for `.eightcol` and `.fourcol` add up to more than 100%. Some browsers may round decimal values differently than others.

```
65.4546% + 3.63636% + 30.9091% = 100.00006%
```

Here's a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/AvXXC/) where you can see that the right column breaks in IE6/7 but is fine in all other browsers.

It's possible that this CSS grid wasn't built to support IE6/7. If all else fails, you could edit or override some of the widths or margin values in the CSS grid. But the changes would have to be reapplied everytime the CSS grid is upgraded. Not sure if there's an easier solution.

**Edit:** For comparison purposes, here's a version of the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/AvXXC/1/) with integer percents that add up to exactly 100%.

Comment: Hmm...I see what you mean but despite chopping off 0.1% from .eightcol it still breaks.

Comment: If I reduce the margin by 0.01%, or if I reduce the right column by 0.1% it seems to work. If I reduce the left column by 0.1% it seems to work as well (at least, the last few times I tried it).

Comment: I managed to chop the margin by 0.05% which got the image to the right corner, but it also caused the bottom half of the layout to break as if the clear:both was not having any effect.  See http://www.tentenstudios.com/misc/broken.jpg

Comment: I might just use <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> and have IE7 people suck one.

Comment: The decimal-rounding results appear to vary based on the size of the parent container. If I resize the live web page, the right column toggles between breaking and not breaking. Wondering if integer % values would be anymore stable.

Comment: Well, I could go that route but I'm still stuck with the fact that the browser seems to forget clear:both after .eightcol and .fourcol.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll just force non-compatibility mode and hope for the best then.  Thanks for spotting the difference in percentages on the columns though!